# Search for characters in a string using blueprism

Tags: blueprism

str1 ="HEADINGLEY";
str2 ="HDNGLY";
how can i search string 1 to see if it contains all the characters from string 2 in the order they exist in string 2 and return a true or false value using blueprism.

I tried using contains and Filter in Utility- Collection Manipulation

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a way of using the provided utilities to perform this exact action.

It’s easily done in a custom VBO however.

If you create a new page in **Utility - Strings**, give it inputs of the *TARGET* and *LETTERS* strings and a *Flag* output (I've called mine ORDERMATCH), you can use some vb in a **Code** stage such as the below to return a True/False value.

```
Dim CurPosition as Integer
Dim LastPosition as Integer

ORDERMATCH = False
CurPosition = 0
LastPosition = 0

For Each c As Char in LETTERS
    CurPosition = TARGET.IndexOf(c)
    If CurPosition > LastPosition Then 
        ORDERMATCH = True
    Else 
        ORDERMATCH = False
        Exit For
    End If
    LastPosition = CurPosition
    CurPosition = 0
Next
```

It is also possible to perform this task with an object or process that follows the same basic steps:

[image]